# Spawn command not working in electron app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron, spawn

I am trying to run a command using spawn using AngularJS in Electron , I am getting an error.

```
events.js:183 Uncaught Error: spawn dita ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1024)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180)
_errnoException @ util.js:1024
ChildProcess._handle.onexit @ internal/child_process.js:190
onErrorNT @ internal/child_process.js:372
_combinedTickCallback @ internal/process/next_tick.js:138
_tickCallback @ internal/process/next_tick.js:180
```

This is my **spawn command** :-

```
spawn('dita', 
            ['--input=C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\ditamaps\mobile-phone\mobilePhone.ditamap', '--output=C:\Users\aaa\Desktop', '--format=pdf'],
            {
              cwd: $scope.ditaPath + "\\bin"
            }, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
              // work with result
              console.log(stdout);
              console.log(stderr);
              console.log(error);
            });
```

When I am running the same batch code manually it's working fine. 
 What is this error? I am not able to get this.

Comment: What did you mean by running it manually?

Comment: @JanithKasun means by running the  command in command prompt. ie; `dita --input=C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\ditamaps\mobile-phone\mobilePhone.ditamap --output=C:\Users\aaa\Desktop --format=pdf`

Answer (score 1):

creating a process with spawn is not same as running it on the command prompt, You may either pass the absolute path of your executable like,

```
spawn('/full/path/to/dita',
    ['--input=C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\ditamaps\mobile-phone\mobilePhone.ditamap', '--output=C:\Users\aaa\Desktop', '--format=pdf'],
    {
        cwd: $scope.ditaPath + "\\bin"
    }, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        // work with result
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

or if you want to emulate command prompt

```
spawn('cmd.exe',
    ['dita', '--input=C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\ditamaps\mobile-phone\mobilePhone.ditamap', '--output=C:\Users\aaa\Desktop', '--format=pdf'],
    {
        cwd: $scope.ditaPath + "\\bin"
    }, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        // work with result
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

both of the solution should work, but in your scenario i guess 2nd one may easy to implement.

Comment: It's working .  Though `cmd.exe` was throwing error , don't know why, but when I changed that to `dita.bat` which was n the directory , it worked . thanks for your help.